# New line after <li> bullet

Tags: html

I have a strange behaviour I can't explain: when I'm writing an easy html file with a `<li>` tag followed with a header (or any tag actually), I have a linebreak between the bullet and the content...

Here is a quick example:

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
    
    <li>
     <h1>First topic</h1>
     <p>Bla bla bla</p>
    </li>
    <li>
     <h2>Second topic</h2>
     <p>Bla bla bla</p>
    </li>
```

Comment: You can not have list items floating in open space - they need to be inside a list element.

Comment: Maybe because your `<li>` is not wrapped in `<ul>`/`<ol>`?

Comment: Yes, sounds like I have to wrap it between ul or ol... I just found it strange: `<ul><li><h2>Title</h2></li></ul>` Does not give a new line |
<br>- `<li>Title</li>` Does not give a new line |
`<li><h2>Title</h2></li>` Gives a new line. I guess I have to force the behaviour with a bit of css to do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valid html does require either an `<ol>` or `<ul>` wrapper around your `<li>`s. However the "extra line spacing" that you are observing between list elements is likely inherent top margins on the `<h1>` and `<h2>` elements or bottom margin on the `<p>` tags.   You can remove that spacing by adding css to eliminate top and bottom margin or padding around those elements when nested in an `<li>`

An example of such css might be:

```
li p, li h1, li h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Ideally, you should add classes to target and style the elements so you don't inadvertently change the margins and padding page/site wide.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought... In the tutorial I'm following, they don't have this new line between the bullet and the next element. Maybe the specifications for css have changed since...

Comment: If you haven't defined any css for your project, then it inherits your browser's default css.  Any block elements in html (lists, paragraphs, headings) typically have margins associated with them.

Comment: Also, an easy way to determine what specific elements are being assigned margin would be to use the browser's inspector. Then you can not only determine how much the margin or padding is, but also where said style rules are coming from.

Comment: Actually, the css to add is more something like that if I want my behavior: `li>h2 {display:inline;}`

Answer (score 1):

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
    
<ul>        
    <li>
     <h1>First topic</h1>
     <p>Bla bla bla</p>
    </li>
    <li>
     <h2>Second topic</h2>
     <p>Bla bla bla</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) for more a bit more information about lists in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put unordered list tags before your list items tags?
for example:

```
<ul>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is becouse of you used H1 element.
This element is block element, it move line automatically.
try to use span insread or force the h1 element to be inline element by any css, like:

```
h1{

     display:inline;
}
```

Comment: `li>h2 {display:inline;}` is more accurate ;)